# AngularJS how many ways is it possible to pass data to a directive other than scope?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I know one way and that is using scope. What are the other ways of doing the same?

This is the custom directive. Here i am creating some custom attributes that pass the data from HTML to the directive via scope.

```
module.directive('createFormButtons', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: { isUpdate: '=isUpdate', saveForm: '=saveForm', saveData: '=saveData', isChange: '=isChange', isPrint: '=isPrint', isTabIndex: '=isTabIndex' },
        templateUrl: 'components/common/createFormButtons.html',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.printpages = false;
            $scope.save = function () {
                $scope.$emit('save');
            };

            $scope.update = function () {
                $scope.$emit('update');
            };

            $scope.refresh = function () {
                $scope.$emit('refresh');
            };

            $scope.newForm = function () {
                $scope.$emit('newForm');
            };

            $scope.print = function () {
                $scope.printpages = !$scope.printpages;
            };

            $scope.printing = function (v) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                if (v === 5)
                    $scope.printpages = !$scope.printpages;
                else
                    $scope.$emit('print', v);

            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

This is how I call it on the HTML.

```
<create-form-buttons style="height:400px;" is-print="true" is-update="isUpdate" is-change="isChange" save-form="inwardForm" save-data="inward">

</create-form-buttons>
```

Comment: You are using the `$scope` variable, it's the best way to do so, why change ?

Comment: @Nicolas He is not asking for changes, but for other possibilities.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [what's on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question is far too broad. Asking for all the other ways of passing data around is essentially infinite.

Comment: Sorry but I have not asked for all the other ways. Can you read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

- You can `$parse` something that's on the `attrs` object.
- You can `$broadcast` data from above and listen for it in the directive using `$scope.$on()`
- You can store data in an angular service and inject this into your directive.

Comment: Ya thanks for your response. I would like to implement the same.

Answer (score -1):

> *What are the other ways of doing the same?*

*What are you trying to achieve*?

If you want to be able to pass in attributes through your views, then the method you already use should be sufficient.

Like @retoheusser mentioned, another way is to create a service or a factory and inject that into your directive if you need to access data through a network request or some other data source.

Your directive can also have a `model` bound to it and you can access properties on it in your directive.

Comment: Actually the question was asked to me by an interviewer and I couldn't answer it. anyways thanks for your response.